# "Do not disturb" notification turning on all on its own

Tags: do-not-disturb

has anyone noticed on their Android phone, that their "Do not disturb" function would be turning on all on its own every now and then? I've experienced this a few times on my Android 12 phone.

Comment: First of all, you might want to check the current settings for Do not disturb (particularly, "Schedules"), because they can have automatic triggers, like based on time, calendar events, etc.

Comment: Do your phone have switch for mute/do not disturb? It can happen you by accident move this switch.